# vscode multi-command extension: how to combine workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText + workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, key-bindings

In vscode, I'm trying to send a line selection to the terminal followed by a "\n" character.
I tried the extension multi-command with the following setup:

settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
        {
            "command": "multiCommand.mycommand",
            "sequence": [
                "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                    "args": {"text": "\n"}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

keybindings.json:

```
{
      "key": "ctrl+alt+i",
      "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
      "args": {"command": "multiCommand.mycommand"}
}
```

But it only runs the first command in the sequence: "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText".

How can I fix this to run the entire sequence?

I already tried to add keybindings to the commands separately in the keybindings.json and it works:

```
{
        "key": "ctrl+alt+a",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText"
},
{
      "key": "ctrl+alt+s",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": {
        "text": "\n"
      }
}
```

So I thoght multi-command should work when defining a sequence with this two commands.

Comment: you have to send `\ux000d`

Comment: Hi rioV8. It does not work, just printed \ux00d at the end without going to the next line. Thanks anyway!

Comment: oops mixed HTML and JSON literals, use `\u000D`

Comment: `\u000D` is a Unicode return, see https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm.